# Caliburn Micro - Detect dormant or Tombstone navigate to login view

Tags: windows-phone-8, caliburn.micro

i use a caliburn micro. In my app i detect a dormant or Tombstone state in AppBootStrapper.cs

```
protected override void OnActivate(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e){}
```

i would "REDIRECT" app on my login page(always)
not is possibile use NavigationService in AppBootStrapper?

For example

```
protected override void OnActivate(object sender, ActivatedEventArgs e) 
{
   NavigationService.UriFor<LoginViewModel>().Navigate();
```

}

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using PhoneContainer then the Navigation Service is registered with the container in the method RegisterPhoneServices.

```
container.RegisterPhoneServices(RootFrame);
```

From there you can request the Navigation Service from the container and do the Navigation.

```
var navigationService = container.GetInstance<INavigationService>();
```